# Grabbing Magento phtmls from outside of Magento while keeping data intact

Tags: magento, frameworks, enterprise

How do I get the content of the following files 
    `frontend/enterprise/default/template/page/html/header.phtml` or
    `frontend/base/default/template/page/template/links.phtml` or
    `frontend/enterprise/default/template/checkout/cart/cartheader.phtml`

outside of Magento and still have the processed date intact.
Like what I mean is still showing the correct number of items for the user 'My Cart (5)', or in the header it says 'Welcome, volkan yavuz' and still show the user's name.

Why do I want this?

I have an zend application independent from Magento which we are trying to combine header and footers, so we'll have them in one place. We need to call Magento header from this zend application.

So far I created a custom API in Magento that calls these files (phtml) but I can't seem to get those processed data (like cart number or welcome first name last name messsage for the current session/user.

Answer (score 1):

In order for these to render with the correct data & state, they must have the correct rendering environment.

```
<?php
include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('store_code');

//Load the session so we get quotes.
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'))->start();
/*
   see Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::preDispatch()
   and Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::preDispatch()
*/

//For each block you wish to render, you could do the following:
$output = Mage::app()->getLayout()
                     ->createBlock('block/type')
                     ->setTemplate('template/path.phtml')
                     ->toHtml();
```

You might choose to make a containing block for all of your blocks, set your blocks as children of this block, make the appropriate template & `getChildHtml()` calls therein, and then you need only call `toHtml()` on that block.

HTH!